# encounter SequelizeEagerLoadingError when I joined two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've following error message, when I joined two tables in `mysql`.

**Teachers**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    const Teachers = sequelize.define('Teachers', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
            autoIncrement: true, 
            primaryKey: true 
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Teachers.hasMany(models.Students);
            }
        }
    });
    return Teachers;
}
```

**Students**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    const Students = sequelize.define('Students', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
            autoIncrement: true, 
            primaryKey: true 
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            validate: {
                isEmail: true
            }
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Students.belongsTo(models.Students);
            }
        }
    });
    return Students;
}
```

and

```
exports.allRegisteredStudents = function (teacherId) {
    return models.Teachers.findAll({
        where: {
            id: teacherId
        },
        include: [models.Students]
    });
};
```

Please let me know what I missed to add, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Students shouldn't be belongs to students model students should be belongs to Teachers Model
It should be like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
const Students = sequelize.define('Students', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        autoIncrement: true, 
        primaryKey: true 
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING, 
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            Students.belongsTo(models.Teachers);
        }
    }
});
return Students;
```

}

And

```
exports.allRegisteredStudents = async function (teacherId) {
return await models.Teachers.findAll({
    where: {
        id: teacherId
    },
    include: [{ model: models.Students }]
});
```

};

Comment: Sorry, it's my `typo`. It's still happening even I've changed to `Students.belongsTo(models.Teachers);`.

Comment: still happening, bro.

Comment: what is the associated column in students model? is there any column like student_id ?

Comment: I've described all my table structure above.

Comment: @PPShein you missed association column in teacher model like student_id otherwise you won't get any results without association.

Comment: Yap, I have not found `student_id` in that table when I checked like `SHOW CREATE TABLE `Teachers`;`

Comment: Could you tell me how could I fixed it?

Comment: create migration file and add_column student_id in teachers table. Follow this http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html link.